# Phone number validation with min and max value - Contact form 7

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

```
<div class="grid">
<label> Name* </label>
 [text* your-name]
</div>

<div class="form-grid"><label> E-mail address* </label>
[email* your-email]
</div>
<div class="form-grid">
  <label> Mobile number </label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      [countrytext* countrytext-284 "india"]
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     [tel tel-396]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>     
 <div class="form-grid">
     <label> What’s your project about?* </label>
    [textarea* your-message] 
  </div>
<div class="input_holder">[submit "Get in touch"]</div>
```

Hey guys, I'm trying to do a contact section using contact form 7. But the problem I'm facing is the phone number validation is not perfect. Not showing any error messages or something when we type only 2-3 digits or more than 15 digits. Also if are typing words instead of numbers it not showing errors.
How can we solve this? Can you help me?

Comment: Where are you able to type text, tel or countrytext?

Comment: Hi Sheedo thanks for your replay. We will type numbers in tel field.

Comment: But you're saying you're able to type text in it?

Comment: Yes I'm able to type in that field. But the problem is I couldn't validate the phone number. That phone number field is still silent whatever the error. Not showing any error message.

Comment: The error message might be hidden with CSS. See if it appears when changing the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to specify *minlength* and *maxlength* like so:

```
[tel* tel-396 minlength:4 maxlength:15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use this function

```
function custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel( $result, $tel )
 { 
 $result = preg_match( '/^\(?\+?([0-9]{1,4})?\)?[-\. ]?(\d{10})$/', $tel ); 
 return $result;
 } 
 add_filter( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel', 10, 2 );
```

Or you can use this plugin also https://wordpress.org/plugins/international-telephone-input-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: Can you try plugin

Comment: Try this and let me know  [number* your-telephone minlength:10 maxlength:140 placeholder "Telephone number"]

Comment: Ok will try Harsh Khare . And this is the validation I'm expecting. http://fima.co/contact/

Comment: You can install a plugin and put a code in the contact form. after that, you can put function code in your function.php file